# retrieving a special search result from facebook in python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve the information contained here for example https://www.facebook.com/search/str//keywords_blended_posts using a python script.

So, I tried using graph API-naturally-, the problem is, there is no option to get the result I'm looking for (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#search), unless I am missing something.
So am I missing something? Is there a way to get the desired url I'm looking for (with providing a token for example) ?

Comment: No, there is no allowed way. Graph API search, and the search functionality users have access to via the UI, are two separate things. And the first one is pretty limited, much likely on purpose.

Comment: Is there a way I can do that, without using graph API?

Comment: No allowed one.

Comment: I'm willing to take a shot(even if it's not allowed)